# How to use hierarchical navigation in a carousel page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I am working in Xamarin forms and I have pages with list views where, if the user taps an item in the list, it takes them to a detail page by push async. I want to have this listview page be part of a carousel page, but that appears to be impossible because carousel page only takes ContentPages as its children and in order to use push async, I have to make the listview page a NavigationPage. I was looking online and I found one person who said they got around this by making the carousel page a child of a NavigationPage, but I'm not sure how that would work or if it even does. If someone could point me in the right direction here, that would be great. Thanks for any help! bump bump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered this yourself.  You can put a `CarouselPage` inside of a `NavigationPage`.  I have tested this and it works.

Here is how I did it.  I created a `CarouselPage` called `MainCarouselPage` and put in three content pages (The `CarouselContentPage` simply displays the page number in it's constructor):

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainCarouselPage : CarouselPage
{
    public MainCarouselPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int i=1; i< 3; i++)
        {
            Children.Add(new CarouselContentPage(i));
        }
        Title = "Carousel Page";
    }
}
```

Then in my app.xaml.cs file I implemented the constructor like this:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainCarouselPage());
}
```

Then, from inside the `ContentPage`s of your `CarouselPage` you can call `Navigation.PushAsync()` to go to other pages in your app.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. I was trying to use a blank navigation page and then push the carousel page onto that navigation page because I thought a carousel page couldn't be a navigation page. Conclusion: I'm dumb. Thanks for the help m8.